# How get a new datatable after reordering the gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I populate a gridview from the db.
then i re arranged the rows in the gridview with javascript code.
i want to copy the rearranged gridview to a datatable
how it possible??

Answer (score 0):

If you re-arranged your data using Javascript, you will have to update the database using Javascript. You will not be able to do if using server-side code.

Getting data and binding a `GridView` on the server-side and then rearranging it with Javascript is not a good idea. I suggest you either get your data purely from Javascript, or arrange your data on the server side before `binding` your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple methods

**First method**

GridView row would have a hidden field in each row which should be updated with new row index and have a column for row index / order in database.

When user changes the row index of GridView Row, you will have to change the hidden fields of all effected with new rowindex. On server side you will have to iterate through the GridView rows and save the respective rows index / order in row column for order of row.

**Second Method**

You can send the changed rows index on each arrangement using the ajax [(jquery ajax)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and save the changed index in database row order column.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to sort the gridview without reloading the page , then use an update panel enable and code for gridview **pageindexchanging** and **sorting** event , if you need any indication while processing use an **updateprogress** control .

If you are intended to update the data . then use **ajax** to send the data to a **webmethod** and update it into DB